# Unable to assign default constraint in an existing column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, alter-table

I am using SQL Server and have a table `Employee`. I want to change the constraint of `Starting_Date` from `NULL` to `NOT NULL` and add a `DEFAULT` with `GETDATE()` function. Please check the screenshot and suggest how to solve the error I get:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this `TSQL` command for add, **not null** constraint

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employee] ALTER COLUMN [Starting_Date] DataTime NOT NULL;
```

If your table had any rows with `null Starting_Date`  run this query before adding the constraint

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Employee] SET Starting_Date = [dbo].[GetDate]() WHERE Starting_Date = NULL;
```

and then this, for **default constraint** from your function output result

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employee]
ADD CONSTRAINT df_Starting_Date
DEFAULT([dbo].[GetDate]())FOR Starting_Date;
```